# Using Batch Script I want to get filename of every file in the directory one by one so that I may perform a specific operation on each of them

Tags: batch-file, biztalk

I want to get filename of every file with specific extension in a folder **one by one** ( something like foreach loop ) actually I am consuming them in a BizTalk application so being able to get it one by one is very important.

Comment: So, this really isn't a duplicate because of the BizTalk factor.  There may be a better solution to OP's actual problem by using a BizTalk pattern.

Comment: Please ask your question again but describe the situation you have with your BizTalk app.  A batch file probably isn't part of the solution.

Comment: If you do want to use a batch script then the solutions that are linked to will help you start.  Just get the script to move the files one by one with a slight delay to another folder where BizTalk picks them up.   But files are a really bad way to do ordered processing.  So you may want to edit your question to clarify your requirements rather than just specifying mandating a certain pattern & technology.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question but I am afraid I have no other option except using batch files as I have already automated a lot of Biztalk tasks using Batch script and can't really change it at this point